# Confused with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

1st php

```
$message=$_POST['message'];      
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT m.title,p.id,p.paid,s.time,bs.seat FROM `booked_seats` bs,`movie` m,`payment` p,`booking` b,`show` s WHERE bs.booking_id=b.id and m.id=s.movie_id and p.booking_id=b.id and b.show_id=s.id and p.id IN($message)");
    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

2nd

```
$mess=$_POST['message'];         
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT m.title,p.id,p.paid,s.time,bs.seat FROM `booked_seats` bs,`movie` m,`payment` p,`booking` b,`show` s WHERE bs.booking_id=b.id and m.id=s.movie_id and p.booking_id=b.id and b.show_id=s.id and p.id IN(:message)");
    $query_params = array(
    ':message' => $_POST['message']);

    $STH->execute($query_params);
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Lets say my message is "31,32,33,34"

When i run the first php i get the correct results
when i run the second one i get only results for id 31.Can someone explain this to me?

Seems like the second select is like SELECT .... p.id IN('31,32,32') 
and the first one is SELECT .... p.id IN(31,32,32).

Comment: you have not bind your `$query_params` in your query.

Comment: remove `$query_params` and add this `$STH->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message'],PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: i am sorry at copy paste i somehow deleted this ...i edited my post

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola i did... i still get only the results for the first id...

Comment: Plain PDO parameter binding is only meant for individual values/strings, not lists. Common/inefficient workaround is `FIND_IN_SET()` in place of `IN` clauses.

Comment: @mario so should stick to my first php ?

Comment: Add this as your last line `$STH->debugDumpParams();` you would definitely find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

`$STH->bindValue(':message', $mess, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

`$STH->execute();`

Comment: what do you post on `$_POST['message']` an array ?

Comment: if you use just plain text `PARAM_STR` should work, otherwise if u use only numbers you can use `PARAM_INT`

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
$mess=$_POST['message'];         
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT m.title,p.id,p.paid,s.time,bs.seat FROM `booked_seats` bs,`movie` m,`payment` p,`booking` b,`show` s WHERE bs.booking_id=b.id and m.id=s.movie_id and p.booking_id=b.id and b.show_id=s.id and p.id IN(:message)");
$query_params = array(
':message' => "'".$_POST['message']."'");

$STH->execute($query_params);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```